# How to skip a feature in cypress so that its not tested for end to end tests

Tags: javascript, angular, cypress

How to skip a feature in cypress so that its not tested for end to end tests

**Tech**: **Angular 8 with cypress versions:**

- "cypress": "^3.4.1"
- "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^1.16.2"
- "cypress-pipe": "^1.4.0"

I'm using cypress with its test runner (./node_modules/.bin/cypress open).

I'm having trouble skipping a test. 
I understand how to @focus on a feature like so:

```
Feature: App is alive
  checking data

  @focus
  Scenario: Read list of data
    Given I open up the page
    Then I see more than one row of data
```

I've tried changing  @focus to  @skip and @skipped but didnt work

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can use [tags](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-example#tags-usage) :

```
Feature: My very feature

  @ignore-this
  Scenario: I don't want to run
    Given I open up the page
    Then I see more than one row of data

  Scenario: I want to run
    Given I open up the page
    Then I see more than one row of data
```

Then run Cypress and setting env **TAGS** accordingly:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress open -e "TAGS=not @ignore-this"
```

If you want an entire feature to be ignored when using **cypress run**, you can use [cucumber tags wrapper](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-example#simple-example) (it won't work with 'open' command, see:[cypress-tags.js](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/cypress-tags.js#L62))

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags run -e TAGS='not @ignore'
```

References:
- https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-example#tags-usage

Comment: I'm not getting any error when I add @ignore to all scenarios within a feature. This works. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried again, you're right, I probably made a mistake during my tests, thanks !
- edited my post

Comment: @ReturnEnd i am trying to run tagged scenario, that is working file but non tagged marked as skip. Is there any way I can avoid that?

Comment: How would we skip a test conditionally? Let say there is no data in the database and we need to skip it conditionally

Comment: Seems like they've already added the `@skip` tag.